# Find instances of consecutive occurrences of char in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to find the best way to check of string for consecutive occurrences of the same character. The same particular character. In my case an underscore @"_".

I need to be able to determine if there are more than underscore side by side and strip out all but one that that range.

EX.

@"THIS_STRING"   This is ok.

@"THIS__STRING"  Needs to be @"THIS_STRING"

@"ANOTHER____STRING_HERE     Needs to be @"ANOTHER_STRING_HERE"

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I did this in Swift so I don't know if it translates exactly to Obj-C but this should work:

```
var string = "NOM__NOM____NOM_NOM"
while (string.rangeOfString("__") != nil) {
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("__", withString "_", options:nil, range: nil)
}
// string is now "NOM_NOM_NOM_NOM"
```

**Edit:**
Here is the working code in Objective-C

```
NSString *string = @"NOM__NOM___NOM_NOM";
while ([string rangeOfString:@"__"].location != NSNotFound) {
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"__" withString:@"_"];
}
// string is now @"NOM_NOM_NOM_NOM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSRegularExpresion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and specifically the method -stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate: